# How to make many functions by onPress according to index?

Tags: react-native

I have a map and i want if i onpress on each this item  making a function according to the index

```
  <ActionSheet
            ref={o => this.ActionSheet = o}
            title={'Which one do you like ?'}
            options={['Delete', 'Edit','Hide', 'Cancel']}
            cancelButtonIndex={3}
            destructiveButtonIndex={1}
           onPress={(index) => { ?????????}
          />
```

i want if i press on index= 0 make this function >>this.delete
and if the index = 1 make this fuction >>Actions.editpost..
How can i do that??

Comment: what do you mean by make a function? Do you mean call a function? or actually construct a function definition?

Comment: call a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly call function like:

```
       deleteFunction = () =>{
          console.log('write your delete functionality');
          console.log('you can use ref this.ActionSheet.show()');
        }

        editFunction = () =>{
          console.log('write your edit functionality');
        }

    render(){
     return(


          <ActionSheet
                    ref={o => this.ActionSheet = o}
                    title={'Which one do you like ?'}
                    options={['Delete', 'Edit','Hide', 'Cancel']}
                    cancelButtonIndex={3}
                    destructiveButtonIndex={1}
                    onPress={(index) => {
                     if(index === 0){
                       this.deleteFunction();
                     }else if(index === 1){
                       this.editfunction();
                     }
                   }
                  />
      )
    }
```